# When toolbar back button is pressed

Tags: android

how can I create a condition on my android app where When I pressed the back button on the toolbar some code will happening.

I tried this but it doesnt work.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    stopTimerTask();
}
```

Comment: *I tried this but it doesnt work.* define: doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement android Toolbar Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327051/how-to-implement-android-toolbar-back-button)

Comment: Isn't `onBackPressed` for the *hardware* back button?

Comment: @Batz Pogi try my answer

Comment: @Selvin - the timer doesnt stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // this takes the user 'back', as if they pressed the left-facing    

      triangle icon on the main android toolbar.
        // if this doesn't work as desired, another possibility is to call   

        `finish()` here.
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Toolbar manipulations.

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.themeToolbarColor));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.left_arrow_thick);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
                //write your code here
                stopTimerTask();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just used below code:-

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_nav_back));
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("cek", "home selected");
//do something here
    }
});
```